# $file->isValid() returns false in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-4.2

```
$file = Input::file('video');
dd($file,$file->isValid());
```

`enctype="multipart/form-data"` is set in the form.

`max_upload_limit` is also increased and **apache restarted**

`$file` has the file, but `$file->isValid()` is always returning false.

Comment: What is the size of file ?

Comment: size of file is 3.3 mb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the `php.ini` file. Find these lines in the php.ini file and replace it following numbers

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

Save the changes and refresh your website and try uploading the file again.

---

Retrieving An Uploaded File

```
$file = Input::file('photo');
```

Determining If An Uploaded File Is Valid

```
if (Input::file('photo')->isValid())
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Solved there was "php5.6-fpm" installed on the server. I was restarting the apache server. But i have to run "sudo service php5.6-fpm restart" after making changes to the upload_max_filesize in the "php.ini" file.